# exceptions.TypeError: 'str' object is not callable when i select data from sqlite3 with python

Tags: python, sqlite

Here call this method.

```
item_date = item['time_y_m_d']
self.sqlite_manger._select_table_by_name(item_date)
```

Here the `table_name` is Chinese characters and encoded with "`utf-8`".

```
def _select_table_by_name(self,table_name):
    c = self.conn.cursor()
    c.execute("select * from sqlite_master where type='%s' and name='%s'" %('table',table_name)) # here exceptions.TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
    r = c.fetchone()
    if r is not None:
        return True
    return False
```

And I get the following error when running the program:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 578, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/Users/zhang/Programs/Python/news/baidu_news/baidu_news/pipelines.py", line 44, in process_item
if self.sqlite_manger._select_table_by_name(item_date):
File "/Users/zhang/Programs/Python/news/baidu_news/baidu_news/sqlite_manager.py", line 62, in _select_table_by_name
c.execute("select * from sqlite_master where name='%s'" % item_date)
exceptions.TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Here is my create table sql:

```
def _create_table_by_date(self,date):
    print 'create table %s' % date
    self.conn.execute(" create table '%s' (p_id integer, title text, link text primary key, source text, time_y_m_d text, time_h_m text)" % date)
    self.conn.commit()
```

I use SQLite3 and Python 2.7.9,and I use this code above in Scrapy project.
Here is the exceptions:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg/scrapy/middleware.py", line 62, in _process_chain
    return process_chain(self.methods[methodname], obj, *args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Scrapy-0.24.4-py2.7.egg/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 65, in process_chain
    d.callback(input)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 383, in callback
    self._startRunCallbacks(result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 491, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()

--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Twisted-15.0.0-py2.7-macosx-10.6-intel.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 578, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/zhang/Programs/Python/news/baidu_news/baidu_news/pipelines.py", line 39, in process_item
    r = self.sqlite_manger._select_key_word(self.word)
  File "/Users/zhang/Programs/Python/news/baidu_news/baidu_news/sqlite_manager.py", line 51, in _select_key_word
    c.execute("select * from category where title='%s'" % word)
exceptions.TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: in 'c.execute('....')'  cast an exception(exceptions.TypeError: 'str' object is not callable)

Comment: Can you provide the table name and relevant error output? I don't have a problem creating a table with a Chinese name.

Comment: @user3467349 table name is "2015年03月07日"

Comment: File "/Users/zhang/Programs/Python/news/baidu_news/baidu_news/pipelines.py", line 44, in process_item
     if self.sqlite_manger._select_table_by_name(item_date):
   File "/Users/zhang/Programs/Python/news/baidu_news/baidu_news/sqlite_manager.py", line 62, in _select_table_by_name
     c.execute("select * from sqlite_master where name='%s'" %tablename )
 exceptions.TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Yes I just tried creating this table and using your query. You are doing something else wrong - and I can't tell without the error output. (Please edit your question and use a code-block, also add sqlite and python version).

Comment: @user3467349 i am not use makedowm , i use sqlite3 and python 2.7.9

Comment: Please add your `sqlite3.version` and your table creation process. This works for me without error in both python2 and python3.

Comment: @user3467349 I have edited my question.  I wander it occurs errors in a Scrapy project.....